# How do I properly install Nethack Learning Environment?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, conda, nethack

Trying to install Nethack Learning Environment (nle) according to their github: https://github.com/facebookresearch/nle

I am running windows 10 x64. I successfully installed all required packages (conda, cmake, cuda, gym, stable-baselines3, even graphviz which someone online said would help) and still return an error when I execute the following:

```
(nle) C:\Users\g>pip install nle
```

I get the following error:

```
 Collecting nle
  Using cached nle-0.8.1.tar.gz (6.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\envs\nle\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\envs\nle\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\envs\nle\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ahobsdbu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ahobsdbu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ahobsdbu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 482, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ahobsdbu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 127, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\envs\nle\lib\subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\envs\nle\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\envs\nle\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\envs\nle\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have even tried installing without the conda environment, via

```
C:\Users\g>pip install nle
```

Which returns the following error:

```
 Collecting nle
  Using cached nle-0.8.1.tar.gz (6.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\g\miniconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4okewis9'
       cwd: C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b2kh8tw6\nle_afe88c6035c142eab966b05f6aa62307
  Complete output (25 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 331, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 117, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-k07q7h5y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-k07q7h5y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-k07q7h5y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 482, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-k07q7h5y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 127, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 505, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/18/f6e78119aa5ab5bc5edffa817e3748100f47b96ca8afb3b39659629b906a/nle-0.8.1.tar.gz#sha256=ab20bf3ef72f79891c70fa0d99abdd41ed77784c0f884c5e9116c552708950a5 (from https://pypi.org/simple/nle/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\g\miniconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\g\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4okewis9' Check the logs for full command output.
```

It then appears to retry installing the package and of course gets stuck at the same point, spitting out the same error.

List of other commands I have tried:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir nle 
pip install ez_setup
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Results:

Same error as before, all three times

Comment: The exception tells you that the install process is trying to run a program (and the program doesn't exist -- at least, not under the stated name). Have you looked at the lines of source in the stack trace to figure out what it's trying to run?

Comment: Also, even though you've _installed_ `cmake` &c., make sure they actually run. `cmake --version` should work, f/e.

Comment: And, really, just _read through_ https://github.com/facebookresearch/nle/blob/main/setup.py. You'll see it trying to call lots of programs -- `git`, `ninja`, and others.

Comment: The other thing, though -- that setup.py lists the supported operating systems, _and Windows isn't one of them_; only "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux" and "Operating System :: MacOS".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.